# How categorize registered users on firebase and flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm working on an app. Where users can find designers. I have a separate page for feeds , where all users can interact and a separate page in which normal users can find designer profile and hire them. Both designers and normal users can sign up similarly but I wanna separate user profile and designer profile and show the designer profiles on a page. Is there a way to do this on firebase. Say I provide a checkbox(click if you're a designer) during sign up . Will I able to store the designer profile in a separate folder on firebase and display that data on the separate page ? Or is there anyother way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 different collections one for designers and another for normal users or you can have both the data in one collection and have a boolean to identify if it's designer or user profile.

Here is an example,
Let the variable `isDesigner` hold true if the profile is designer profile else false.

**First Approach**

Now we can modify the firebase collection reference as follows

```
Firestore.instance.collection(isDesigner?'designer':'normal_user')
```

If its designer profile the data will be store in the `designer` collection and if its normal profile it will be store in the `normal_user` collection.

**Second Approach**

If you don't want to have 2 different collections then you can add a bool in you data to identify if its designer profile or normal user profile and query it like

To get all designer profiles.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('isDesigner',isEqualTo:true).snapshots()
```

To get all normal user profiles.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('isDesigner',isEqualTo:false).snapshots()
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Can please tell me how do I implement that? I'm not that of a coder. I only know the basics

Comment: Hey thankyou so much. I declare all firestore instance in a final variable above the class. So Where do I declare bool isdesigner = true? . It should also sync with the check box i keep in the sign up page. So how to make it work?

Comment: You can declare the variable in the state of you widget and update it according to the checkbox status. I think you should look at some tutorials for the same.

Comment: Can  you please help me with that?I cant find any tutorials